# problems publishing package release to github

Tags: java, maven, github

I am slowly understanding how to publish packages into Git.

My project is called HubspotContacts

Here is the top part of my pom.xml file:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Hubspot</groupId>
      <artifactId>Hubspot</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Here is the distribution management section of my pom.xml file:

```
 <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>dell_packages</id>
     <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://github.com/dell_computers/HubspotContacts</url>
   </repository>
```

Here is my settings.xml file:

```
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>hubspot</activeProfile>   </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>hubspot</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>hubspot</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/dell_computers/Hubspot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>   </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>hubspot</id>
      <username>username</username> <password>long_token_string</password>
    </server>   </servers> </settings>
```

The error I'm getting:

> Transfer failed for https://github.com/dell_computers/Hubspot/Hubspot/ATSHubspotContacts/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ATSHubspotContacts-0.0.1-20200124.182801-1.jar 422 Unprocessable Entity

Can someone help with my config?
Should the URL to the repository be an actual .git ending url or something different?

Comment: Long time but isn't your jar a snapshot and you've snapshots disabled?